# Get tag using class not working in IE 8 & 7

Tags: javascript

My Script

```
var cwidth   = document.getElementById('contentarea').clientWidth;
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("shadow");

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].style.width = cwidth+"px";
   var anc = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("a"); // not working in IE 7 & 8
   anc[0].style.width = cwidth+"px";
}
```

This script working well in all browsers except IE 7 & 8

Any one please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` isn't supported in IE<9.

In IE8 you can use:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".shadow");
```

But keep in mind that it's *not* a live collection like the one you get with `getElementsByClassName`. And if you want to look for elements with multiple classes, you'll have to do `document.querySelectorAll(".first.second");`.

As for IE7, you have to rely on something else, like a weel known framework (like jQuery or just Sizzle), or a function like this:

```
var getElementsByClassName = (function(all) {
    return function (cls) {
        var a = [], i = 0;
        for (; i < all.length; i++)
            if ((" " + all[i].className + " ").indexOf(" " + cls + " ") !== -1)
                a.push(all[i]);
        return a;
    };
})(document.all);
```

This isn't a live collection either, moreover you won't be able to search for elements with multiple classes. That is, unless they are ordered like you want in their `className` property, but you can't rely on that. You'll have to do something more complicated, I'll leave it to you when you'll get more experienced in Javascript.

Comment: wow ! great....thanks ..... can you please explain how to call the IE7 `getElementsByClassName`  ????? can you give one example

Comment: With this: `var elements = getElementsByClassName("shadow");`.

Comment: I beg your pardon, I wrote down `class` instead of `className`.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 and 8 don't have the function 'getElementsByClassName' you can build this function on your own like jQuery does.